# Monitoring LG's ThinQ appliance status

Tags: api, monitoring, home-automation

The LG ThinQ app can be used to determine the status of stove-tops, ovens, TV's, etc., but (I think) must be queried manually.

Is there an app or web page that will continually monitor these devices and notify me when they've been left on for too long, or after midnight?

(Alternatively, is there a simple API for querying these devices, so I can roll my own?)

Comment: Wouldn't life be simpler if they would all actually agree to one standard rather than each inventing their own? Right now I only own 5 things that could be classed as IoT… which require 5 different apps to control them. [actually 6, one has two apps for two control types:\ Compulsory XKCD link - https://xkcd.com/927/